# i have a problem with search using php, mysql

Tags: php, mysql, large-data

I have 50M data in my database (**mysql** phpmyadmin),
when I search inside this data using php it takes a lot of time, very slow

How can i solve this problem?

my code :

```
$mysql_search = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE columns='value'";
$search_query = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_search);

foreach($search_query as $row){
     echo $row['id'];
}
```

and thanks

I've already tried using limit and Like
But nothing happened

```
$mysql_search = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE columns LIKE 'value%' LIMIT 5";
```

Comment: From your MySQL with root login and your slow query running, please post complete TEXT results of SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;.  And POSt complete TET results of SHOW CREATE TABLE data; so we can see ALL your column definitiions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three things I can suggest you that can improve the performance of your search:

**Use an index:** Adding an index on the `column` can significantly improve the performance of your search, especially if you have a large table.In that case on your `column` field where you're trying to do that search. For example:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name_column ON data (column);
```

**Optimize your query:** Make sure that your query is optimized for performance. For example, try to fetch only required fields while searching like

```
$mysql_search = "SELECT filed1, field2 FROM data WHERE columns LIKE 'value%' LIMIT 5";
```

**Use LIMIT and OFFSET**: Select rows that you need only while doing the search. For example: you can combine `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` to narrow down your search results like-

```
$mysql_search = "SELECT field1, field2 FROM data WHERE columns LIKE 'value%' LIMIT 5 OFFSET 10";
```